# ReactJS form onSubmit doesn't work, it's not called

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, jsx

I'm using NodeJS, JSX and ReactJS and I have the next class:

```
import React from 'react';

export default class LoginPage extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {value: ''};

        this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
        this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);

        console.log("QD");
    }

    handleChange(event) {
        console.log("QDWWQD");
        this.setState({value: event.target.value});
    }

    handleSubmit(event) {
        console.log('A name was submitted: ' + this.state.value);
        event.preventDefault();
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
                <input type="submit"/>
            </form>
        );
    }
}
```

I deleted every input and kept just the submit button. When click it the `handleSubmit` function is not called and the page is just refreshed.

EDIT:
Here is my `server.js` routing part:

```
app.get('*', (req, res) => {
match( { routes, location: req.url }, (err, redirectLocation, renderProps) => {
    // in case of error display the error message
    if (err) {
        return res.status(500).send(err.message);
    }

    // in case of redirect propagate the redirect to the browser
    if (redirectLocation) {
        return res.redirect(302, redirectLocation.pathname + redirectLocation.search);
    }

    // generate the React markup for the current route
    let markup;
    var bodyClasses;
    if (req.session.user === undefined) {
        markup = renderToString(<LoginPage/>);

        bodyClasses = "login-page";
    } else if (renderProps) {
        // if the current route matched we have renderProps
        markup = renderToString(<RouterContext {...renderProps}/>);

    bodyClasses = "sidebar-mini";
    } else {
        // otherwise we can render a 404 page
        markup = renderToString(<NotFoundPage/>);
        res.status(404);
    }

    // render the index template with the embedded React markup
    return res.render('index', { markup: markup, bodyClasses: bodyClasses });
});
});
```

And, if it helps, here is `routes.js`:

```
import React from 'react'
import { Route, IndexRoute } from 'react-router'
import Layout from './components/Layout.react';
import IndexPage from './components/IndexPage.react';
import NotFoundPage from "./components/NotFoundPage.react";
import PropertiesPage from "./components/PropertiesPage.react";

const routes = (
    <Route path="/" component={Layout}>
        <IndexRoute component={IndexPage}/>
        <Route path="proprietati" component={PropertiesPage}/>
        <Route path="*" component={NotFoundPage}/>
    </Route>
);

export default routes;
```

EDIT2: Here is the index.ejs:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

    <script src="adminlte/plugins/jQuery/jquery-2.2.3.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body class="hold-transition skin-blue <%= bodyClasses %>">
    <div id="main"><%- markup %></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Really? I tried in JsFiddle and that worked.... http://jsfiddle.net/aasrozqd/

Comment: So the problem is somewhere else? Maybe with the nodejs?

Comment: probably somewherelse... could you provide the code?

Comment: Added more info

Comment: Don't see any problem.. the console.log is not being called right?

Comment: The function is not called at all because also the page refresh, so event.preventDefault() don't get called.

Comment: Really don't know... here if I remove event.preventDefault I got your behaviour ... But If I put that... It works... Try to clean up and rebuild

Comment: This is weird behavior but have you tried replacing <input type="submit" /> with <button type="submit"></button> ?  I have no idea if that will change anything as, as far as I can tell this should be working.

Comment: What does the `index` template look like?

Comment: @Mihai Maybe you have a client-side error and your javascript is never interpreted. You build an isomorphic application (the DOM is rendered server-side), so you have a classic `<form>`, if your javascript is not executed, the `preventDefault()` will not work.

Comment: @Freez Yes, I'm rendering on server-side. How to debug my client then?

Also added the index template.

Comment: You can check if you have errors on your browser devtools , if the script is loaded , just use your browser inspector.

Comment: No errors on the browser console.

Comment: Yes, the problem was that I was not even rendering the client side. Now it's working. You may write an answer in order to mark is as answered.

Answer (score -2):

Try to add return false in:

```
handleSubmit(event) {
    event.preventDefault()
    console.log('A name was submitted: ' + this.state.value);
    return false;
}
```

Comment: As of React v14 returning false doesn't work [here](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/events.html)